# Spring 3.0 RmiProxyFactoryBean: how to change serviceUrl at runtime?

Tags: spring, javabeans, rmi

I have a bean definition like this:

```
    <bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="org.myapp.MyService"/>
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1099/myService"/>
</bean>
```

I retrieve the service bean in this way:

```
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:rmi-client-config.xml");
    MyService myService = context.getBean("myService", MyService.class);
```

Of course it returns an Instance of "MyService" impl and not RmiProxyFactoryBean.

So how can I change "serviceUrl" parameter using the xml definition above and not manually instancing RmiProxyFactoryBean?

Comment: If you want to do that, then manually creating and configuring `RmiProxyFactoryBean` is the best way to go.

Comment: @skaffman Manually created it with **new** works. But calling new again with a new endpoint results in a Connection Exception due to the **cached** old endpoint not being accessible; it doesn't update to use the new endpoint, even though we're using **new** then calling **afterPropertiesSet()** on the *RmiProxyFactoryBean* as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the `FactoryBean` instance instead of the bean created by the factory, use the `BeanFactory.FACTORY_BEAN_PREFIX`. ie

`RmiProxyFactoryBean rpfb = (RmiProxyFactoryBean) contex.getBean("&myService");`

Comment: Great! It is exactly what I was looking for! Then rpfb.setServiceUrl(...) and rpfb.afterPropertiesSet(); make the rest. Thanks!